# javascript backtracking algorithm with strange bahavior

Tags: javascript, algorithm, backtracking

```
let puzzle = [
    [0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 3, 5, 0, 0],
    [6, 0, 5, 4, 0, 8, 3, 0, 2],
    [0, 0, 4, 5, 2, 0, 9, 0, 6],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 1, 2, 0, 9],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [8, 0, 9, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [9, 0, 1, 0, 8, 5, 6, 0, 0],
    [7, 0, 3, 9, 0, 2, 8, 0, 5],
    [0, 0, 8, 7, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
];

class Sudoku 
{

    constructor(puzzle) 
    {
        this.sudoku = puzzle;
    }

    isPossible(y, x, n) 
    {
        for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
        {
            if (this.sudoku[y][i] == n)
                return false;
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
        {
            if (this.sudoku[i][x] == n)
                return false;
        }

        let y0 = (Math.floor(y / 3) * 3);
        let x0 = (Math.floor(x / 3) * 3);
        
        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
        {
            for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
            {
                if (this.sudoku[y0 + i][x0 + j] == n)
                    return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    solve()
    {
        for (let y = 0; y < 9; y++)
        {
            for (let x = 0; x < 9; x++)
            {
                if (this.sudoku[y][x] == 0)
                {
                    for (let n = 1; n <= 9; n++)
                    {
                        if (this.isPossible(y, x, n))
                        {
                            this.sudoku[y][x] = n;
                            this.solve();
                            this.sudoku[y][x] = 0;
                        }
                    }

                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        console.table(this.sudoku);
    }
}

let s = new Sudoku(puzzle);
s.solve();
```

This works fine the way it is written. However, debugging shows that after the `console.table`, the code keeps running and takes the matrix back to its original state. But, the `console.table` line is never executed again. So, outside of the `solve` method, `this.sudoku` is just the original `puzzle` matrix.
Why is this happening? After the output, what is causing the code to keep running? How come it never goes back to the end (`console.table`), and how can I stop it once it has actually solved the puzzle?

Comment: 44 layers of recursion… "Outside" of one `solve()` call is still inside another `solve()` call.

Comment: "*the `console.table` line is never executed again*" - that would mean it found only a single solution. The line might be executed any number of times depending on the puzzle input.

Comment: @Bergi yes, I would expect only one solution most of the time. But my question is, why does it continue to execute ABOVE the output and never reach the output again?

Comment: @Bergi it actually runs something like 870 times. But, only 650 to reach he output.

Comment: "*why does it continue to execute ABOVE the output*" - because there's still a lot of `solve()` calls on the stack that haven't finished their looping, and will simply continue where they left off when the recursive call returns. "*why never reach the output again?*" - only because it doesn't find another solution. If there were multiple solutions, it would reach the output again.

Comment: Unbelievable! publish almost 80 lines of code without any comments!

Comment: @Bergi I can live with all of that... but what is actually happening is that the program is running backwards and the matrix reverts back to its initial state. Also, even if I were to dump the initial output to another array (`this.newarray = this.sudoku`), accessing that new array would show the initial puzzle matrix. How did that information get there?

Comment: @MisterJojo is there something you don't understand? it is matrix manipulation and pretty much self explanatory.

Comment: @aserwin "*the matrix reverts back to its initial state*" - yes, one step at a time. It's going back and forth: backtracking! It will only find and output the solution at maximum depth, with all fields changed, then it will change them back to explore other paths.

Comment: @MisterJojo the hole thing is literally counting nodes in a matrix. The code is pretty explicit. I could add comments that say "counting across 9 rows", etc... but the code pretty much explains itself. There is no actual magic happening!

Comment: @MisterJojo please show me a line that you would like commented upon. If there is something you don't understand, I will gladly explain it. Especially if it will help you to help me resolve my issue.

Comment: @MisterJojo at each point int the matrix we call isPossible to see if the number we are asserting already exists in the y axis, the x axis or in the 3x3 square we are in (as per sudoku rules)... it has nothing to do with why the solve method persists after finding a solution to the entire puzzle.

Comment: @MisterJojo but that doesn't explain why I get a correct output and then the code keeps going, but never reaches the output again.

Comment: because there is only one possibility in one of the recursive call, which is not at the top

Comment: @MisterJojo https://gitlab.com/andrewthecoder/ts-sudokusolver please fork, improve and update!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will do that this way, simply add a `solved` test and some loop break...

```js
const Sudoku = (()=>
  {
  let 
    grid   = null
  , solved = false 
    ;
  const
    nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
  , isPossible = (row, col, num) => 
      {
      for (let c in grid)  if (grid[row][c] === num) return false
      for (let r in grid)  if (grid[r][col] === num) return false
      row -= row %3
      col -= col %3
      for (let i=0, c=col; i<3; i++,c++)
      for (let j=0, r=row; j<3; j++,r++)
        if (grid[r][c] === num) return false
      return true
      }
  , solve = () =>
      {
      for (let row in grid) 
        {
        if (solved) break
        for (let col in grid) 
          {
          if (solved) break
          if (grid[row][col] === 0)
            {
            for (let num of nums)
              if (isPossible(row, col, num))
                {
                grid[row][col] = num
                solve()
                if (solved) break 
                grid[row][col] = 0
                }  
            return
        } } } 
      solved = true
      };
  return (puzzle) =>
    {
    grid   = puzzle
    solved = false
    solve()
    return solved
    }
  })()


const puzzle =
  [ [ 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 3, 5, 0, 0 ]
  , [ 6, 0, 5, 4, 0, 8, 3, 0, 2 ]
  , [ 0, 0, 4, 5, 2, 0, 9, 0, 6 ]
  , [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 1, 2, 0, 9 ]
  , [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
  , [ 8, 0, 9, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
  , [ 9, 0, 1, 0, 8, 5, 6, 0, 0 ]
  , [ 7, 0, 3, 9, 0, 2, 8, 0, 5 ]
  , [ 0, 0, 8, 7, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ]
  ]

let resolved = Sudoku(puzzle)

console.log( resolved ? 'resolved !':'not resolved !','\n' )

console.log(JSON.stringify(puzzle).replaceAll('],[',']\n,['))

// console.table( )  doesn't work on snippet
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
.as-console-row::after {display: none !important;}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is important to see that the console output is reached if and only if there are no if no more open fields in the table (programmatically. matrix elements set to zero).

In any other case the control flow returns from the current function invocation before the output statement is reached

The recursive algorithm dwells on the idea that to solve a given sudoku problem, you pick an open field, pick the first number between 1 and 9 that keeps the tableau consistent with the rules and try to solve this new puzzle by recursively calling the solver. Termination is guaranteed as with each recursive call there is one open field less.

After a recursive call has completed, the choice made immediately before the call is retracted and the remaining possibilities to assign a number to the position are tried, once again ascertaining consistency and recursively calling the solver. This way, *all* solutions to the original puzzle will be found.

The solver is efficient in the sense that it visits every configuration that does not admit another level of recursion ( ie. which is a solution or a dead end ) only once. There is exactly 1 sequence in which the configuration's positions that are open in the start puzzle will be filled.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"   content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="expires"        content="0">
        <meta http-equiv="cache-control"  content="private">
        <meta http-equiv="pragma"         content="no-cache">
        <title>SO - Bitmap (svg)</title>
        <!--
        -->
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background-color:   #eee;
            }
            .board {
                display:    table;
                border:     solid 3px black
            }
            .board > div {
                display:    table-row;
            }
            .cell {
                width:              16px;
                height:             16px;
                display:            table-cell;
                border:             solid 1px lightgrey;
                padding:            5px;
                text-align:         center;
                vertical-align:     middle;
                font-size:          80%;
            }
            .last-square-column {
                border-right:       solid 2px black;
            }
            .last-square-row {
                border-bottom:      solid 2px black;
             }
            .preset {
                color:              blue;
                background-color:   #ddddff;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
let puzzle_orig = [  // The original problem
        [0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 3, 5, 0, 0],
        [6, 0, 5, 4, 0, 8, 3, 0, 2],
        [0, 0, 4, 5, 2, 0, 9, 0, 6],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 1, 2, 0, 9],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [8, 0, 9, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [9, 0, 1, 0, 8, 5, 6, 0, 0],
        [7, 0, 3, 9, 0, 2, 8, 0, 5],
        [0, 0, 8, 7, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
     ]
   ;
 let puzzle = [ // Multiple solutions
        [0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 3, 5, 0, 0],
        [6, 0, 5, 4, 0, 8, 3, 0, 2],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 1, 2, 0, 9],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [8, 0, 9, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [9, 0, 1, 0, 8, 5, 6, 0, 0],
        [7, 0, 3, 9, 0, 2, 8, 0, 5],
        [0, 0, 8, 7, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
    ]
  ;

class Sudoku 
{

    constructor(puzzle) 
    {
        this.sudoku = puzzle;
        this.base   = puzzle.map ( a_row => { return a_row.map ( n_cell => n_cell ); });
        this.n_solutions = 0;
    }

    isPossible(y, x, n) 
    {
        for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
        {
            if (this.sudoku[y][i] == n)
                return false;
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
        {
            if (this.sudoku[i][x] == n)
                return false;
        }

        let y0 = (Math.floor(y / 3) * 3);
        let x0 = (Math.floor(x / 3) * 3);
        
        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
        {
            for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
            {
                if (this.sudoku[y0 + i][x0 + j] == n)
                    return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    out () {
        let e_body  = document.querySelector('body')
          , e_board = document.createElement('div')
          , e_h     = document.createElement('h3')
          ;

        e_h.innerText = `Solution #${this.n_solutions++}`;
        e_board.setAttribute('class', 'board');              
        for (let y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
            let e_row = document.createElement('div')
              ;
              
            for (let x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
                let e_cell = document.createElement('div')
                  ;
                  
                e_cell.innerText = this.sudoku[y][x];
                e_cell.setAttribute('class', 'cell');
                if (this.base[y][x] !== 0) {
                    e_cell.classList.add('preset');
                }
                if ((x === 2) || (x === 5)) {
                    e_cell.classList.add('last-square-column');
                }
                if ((y === 2) || (y === 5)) {
                    e_cell.classList.add('last-square-row');
                }
                e_row.append(e_cell);
            }
            
            e_board.append(e_row);
       }
       e_body.append(e_h);
       e_body.append(e_board);
    } // out
    
    solve()
    {
        for (let y = 0; y < 9; y++)
        {
            for (let x = 0; x < 9; x++)
            {
                if (this.sudoku[y][x] == 0)
                {
                    for (let n = 1; n <= 9; n++)
                    {
                        if (this.isPossible(y, x, n))
                        {
                            this.sudoku[y][x] = n;
                            this.solve();
                            this.sudoku[y][x] = 0;
                        }
                    }

                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        this.out();
    }
}

let s = new Sudoku(puzzle);
s.solve();
                
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I get all that. I wrote the program. What I don't get is why, after reaching the end of the method and dumping its output, does the program keep executing. Also, why does it execute a certain amount of times, never getting back to the return, but continuing to manipulate the global matrix.

Comment: With all due respect, did you read the answer at all? The output is dumped at the top of the call stack and the recursion is not a tail recursion, so it continues to execute. The motivation to proceed after the first output is the possibility of additional solutions. The program in fact _does_ 'get back to the return', with the exception of the innermost recursion level if a solution is output.

Comment: to be honest, when I responded you hadn't finished your response, so I apologize if said response was out of sorts. Thank you for your input. I believe I understand my error now.

Comment: your answer is more complete than mine. I didn't know that a Sudoku could have several answers; which is mathematically logical after all(+)